# Focus buttons with same access key instead of firing the first

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, controls, keyboard-shortcuts

[image]

Pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> **fires** the first button though button 2 has the same access key.

How can I manage to **focus** button 1 on a first <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and to **focus** button 2 on a second <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> without handling keydown event or similar?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Beep.Play();
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Media.SystemSounds.Hand.Play();
}
```

Comment: Maybe use a `bool`, and check if it's `true/false`, to decide which one to focus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override [`ProcessMnemonic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.processmnemonic(v=vs.110).aspx) to customize the behavior of your button when a mnemonic pressed. When processing mnemonic, when you detected the control is in the state that should execute an action based on mnemonic character, return `true`, otherwise return `false`.

In below implementation, the control first checks if the mnemonic belongs to the control, then if it is not `Focuded` then it calls `Focus` and returns true, otherwise (it's focused or it should not handle the mnemonic) returns false. This way it allows the focus move between controls with the same mnemonic:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyButton:Button
{
    protected override bool ProcessMnemonic(char charCode)
    {
        if (this.UseMnemonic && this.Enabled && this.Visible &&
            Control.IsMnemonic(charCode, this.Text))
        {
            if (!this.Focused)
            {
                this.Focus();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```